# Eigenvalue of matrix over (Z/pZ)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

How can I show for $M\in\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ with $\text{ord}(M)=p^n$ ($n$ a positive integer), that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$?

I would be grateful for any hint or advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Show that if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue, then $\alpha^{p^n}=1$.

Comment: Oh sorry! The $d$ isn't more specified on my problem sheet

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Would you embed $M$ in $GL_d(F)$ the splitting field of its characteristic polynomial to show it has some eigenvector ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok, I have shown that. But does from that already follow $\alpha = 1$? Sorry, if that's a trivial question, but I'm not familiar with modular arithmetic

Comment: In characteristic $ p $, there is a marvelous formula called the freshman's dream : $ (x+y)^p = x^p + y^p $.  Can you see how that can help ?

Comment: @Max If $x,y$ commute (they do here)

Comment: @Max Wow, I didn't knew about that! But I'm not really sure: $$(\alpha + x)^p^n = \alpha^p^n + x^p^n = 1 + x^p^n = 1^p^n + x^p^n = (1+x)^p^n $$. Is that it? Edit: I dont know why Latex wont work :(

Comment: You can't put 2 dollar signs in the comments, just one on each side. What happens if you take a specific $ x $ ?

Comment: Since $M,-I$ commute $(M-I)^{p^n} =\sum_{k=0}^{p^n} {p^n \choose k} M^k (-I)^{p^n-k} =M^{p^n}+(-I)^{p^n} = I+(-1)^{p^n} I = 0$ thus $M-I$ isn't inversible thus its kernel is not empty. To go further I would look at the trigonalization or Jordan normal form

Comment: As @reuns basically wrote I would try -1

Comment: @reuns : why go into so much trouble ? $ (M-I)^{p^n} =0 $ so the minimal polynomial of $ M $  is...

Comment: @Max What do you mean ? In general for $M \in M_n(\Bbb{F}_q)$ and a root of its characteristic or minimal polynomial then $M-\lambda I\in M_n(\Bbb{F}_q(\lambda))$ is not inversible so its kernel is not empty thus $M v=\lambda v$ for some $v \in \Bbb{F}_q(\lambda)^n$

Comment: @reuns : yes but you mentioned Jordan normal form or trigonalization : there's no need for these